# How to show data as progress bar and circle percentage progress wheel?

Tags: java, android, layout, progress-bar

I am trying to do something like this in my app:
[image]

But I don't know where to start, should I use the "ProgressBar" in the "Form Widgets" or is there something else? How can such thing be done? what should i bee using? if you have any examples you can link me to i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Progress Wheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

If you configure it right, it can do exactly what you want.

Comment: thank you ill try that and see if it works. But what about the bar?

Comment: A simple `ProgressBar` can do it.